# Confusion with color management - how do I get consistent colors between different viewing tools?

Tags: color-spaces, cinema4d, render-settings, color-management

I'm trying to understand how to color manage to get consistent results but I'm failing spectacularly at it currently. For reference I'm using Cinema 4D with Redshift, working with ACES. On the default setting, Redshift is set to use ACEScg color space, displaying it on sRGB, and applying ACES 1.0 SDR Video on it.

When I render and save it as a PNG, and then open it up in Photoshop of Affinity Photo, it looks completely different. I have Photoshop set to ask me what profile to use whenever it opens a photo - this is part of the confusion. When I save an image off Redshift render as a PNG, and I open it up in Photoshop, what color profile should I choose? From what I've read and watched, I should choose the color profile it was saved with - which in this case is ACEScg, so I should choose that on Photoshop right? Except when I do that, it gets super bright and looks nothing like the render screen.

[image: This is what I see on the render view]

[image: This is what it looks like on Photoshop with ACEScg profile assigned to it]

[image: This is what it looks like with sRGB profile assigned to it]

What exactly is happening when I save an image off the render? Is there a color profile embedded/baked into it? If so, which one? And when I open an image in Photoshop, what profile do I need to use - the one the image was made with, or just sRGB?

For reference, my display is a Dell U2414H, and I'm using Dell's ICC profile for this specific monitor (I can't calibrate it with external tools because they're just a tad bit too expensive for me right now).

[image: These are my current windows color management settings]

EDIT: Additional info. If I open the image and set photoshop to not color manage, it opens as an untagged image. Even then, the colors are still somehow different from the render view and within Photoshop.

[image: The green is a completely different shade!]

Comment: The photos you uploaded are untagged [ie they have no profile attached]. that means they will simply be assumed to be sRGB & we have nothing to go on. Photoshop should be set to not change profile on import, only change at export or if you have to use layers from different sources. You should also never set Photoshop's working profile to your display profile [ can't see from the info posted, but that's a common mistake]

Comment: Also note: I have zero experience with ACES workflows. I found this - https://prolost.com/blog/aces but it's way beyond me ;) A quick look at specs for your display though - it's barely capable of sRGB, so you won't see a lot of ACES or Adobe RGB, which can lead to errors.

Comment: Just tried opening the image without assigning a profile (so leaving it untagged), and it's still different! I'm so confused.

Comment: if it has a profile, then opening it untouched into Photoshop should not show as untagged, it should show the original profile. I'd suspect your prior export isn't saving the profile.

Comment: I *suspect* the ACES profile is *outside* all other profiles and *all* the color shifts are due to the inability to support ACES in external images/apps. i.e. Photoshop **can't** assume color other than the bring *everything* within the range of a profile. The shift you are seeing is similar to moving from RGB to CMYK... some colors are simply *not possible*. While clearly ACESS has benefits, if the goal is a PNG, then perhaps using a more restrictive profile, such as sRGB would be better. I am merely guessing though. I have no direct experience with ACES.

Comment: ACES, as I've read, is for video.. if you're goal is a PNG, ACES is an inappropriate profile to use, since PNGs won't support ACES and 2D image editors aren't going to support ACES for a few years. -- if you want *consistent* color, then you should use a profile which is supported across *all* your editors, not just the 3D editor.

Comment: In short.. I think your *entire* issue is the ACES profile in Cinema when nothing else you are using supports that profile.

Comment: A guess: Your settings convert (=flattens) the high dynamic range content to the usual 8 bit RGB, but its color profile is matched to your display. If you set in Photoshop the working RGB space to "Monitor RGB"  and do not make any color space conversions when opening the exported rendering result , you'll see quite the same as in Cinema4D. Of course this has a possibility to be true only if also your operating system knows and uses your monitor color profile. I do not have high dynamic range video capable software, so this really is guessing.

Comment: One more thing. PNG can support 48 bits, or 16 per channel. See if that has something to do.

Comment: I feel it also has something to do with a "gamma transform" that probably has not been applied. The dark image looks linear, and the bright one with a gamma of 2. I am not sure where that transformation should be.

Comment: @Rafael  Photoshop's 16 bit integers are useless if one tries to open the full ACES high dynamic range image. There the numbers are 16 bit floats. The questioner has already asked his Cinema4D-program to generate a compressed version of the image which has the usual 8 bit RGB depth. His "do not color manage"-attempt is quite close and it would be perfect if his Photoshop happened to use the icc profile of his monitor or the compression in Cinema4D was made to his actual working RGB used in Photoshop, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Photoshop working space should be set to *ACEScg ACES workingspace AMPAS S-2014-004*.

Now you need to make sure your output is really aces because ACEScg bercause it seems like it is not. Note that your viewer needs to do something to the image because your monitor **can not show** ACEScg.

**Side note**: by using ACEScg your not following a ACES workflow.

Comment: Photoshop ought to be able to use an image imported with the ACES profile even without conversion… same as it would for a simpler Adobe 98. I'm certain the OP's colour change is because they're either not embedding the profile in the first place, or discarding it at import. Setting Photoshop to 'unmanaged' would do the same thing, ie completely discard the profile & treat is as 'probably sRGB'.

Comment: @Tetsujin.  you can assign a profile or you can do a profile to profile conversion. But most likely the cinema 3D does not have a profile aware viewer so its done with a lut so what gets saved is not correct. Or then therrs no color management and what he sees in cinema4D is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I was the only one using C4D for single images Photoshop workflow. it seems everything in c4d is currently geared towards animation and ACES workflow. after endless attempts i found a method that works to some extent for the Photoshop sRGB workflow, at least with the latest C4D version 2023.

**In C4D:**
Project Settings: Color Management: Simple / sRGB
Redshift Settings: Color Management:

- Rendering Color Space: scene-linear Rec.709-sRGB
- Display: sRGB
- View: Un-tone-Mapped
- Compensate for View Transform
- Rendering as PNG, TIFF ... 8bit sRGB

**In Photoshop (I assume you are working in the sRGB color space):**

- Assign Profile: Display
- Convert Profile: sRGB

with this method the colors are almost identical to the redshift render view. hope that helps.